# Nestjs Svelte - import apexcharts in Svelte files

Tags: node.js, nestjs, svelte, apexcharts

I am new to Nodejs. I have created a Nestjs project, and I'm using svelte templates. I'm trying to create charts using apexcharts and it works like this:

```
// Chart.svelte
<script>
    import Layout from './partials/Layout.svelte';
</script>
<svelte:head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
    <script src="/js/chart.js" defer></script>
</svelte:head>
<Layout>
    <div id="chart"></div>
</Layout>
```

and the script is something like this:

```
// chart.js
var options = {
    chart: {type: 'bar'},
    series: [{name: 'sales', data: [30,40,45,50,49,60,70,91,125]}],
    xaxis: {categories: [1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997, 1998,1999]}
}
var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
chart.render();
```

but when I tried doing it all in the svelte file like this:

```
// Chart.svelte
<script>
    import Layout from './partials/Layout.svelte';
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    let options = {
        chart: {type: 'bar'},
        series: [{name: 'sales', data: [30,40,45,50,49,60,70,91,125]}],
        xaxis: {categories: [1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997, 1998,1999]}
    };
    let ApexCharts;
    let loaded = false;
    
    const machart = (node, options) => {
        if (!loaded) {
            return;
        }
        let myChart = new ApexCharts(node, options)
        myChart.render();

        return {
            update(options) {
                myChart.updateOptions(options);
            },
            destroy() {
                myChart.destroy();
            }
        }
    }

    onMount(async () => {
        console.log("before import");
        const module = await import('apexcharts');
        ApexCharts = module.default;
        window.ApexCharts = ApexCharts;
        loaded = true;
    });
</script>

<Layout>
    {#if loaded}
    <div use:machart={options}></div>
    {:else}
    <div class="spinner-border text-success" role="status">
        <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
    </div>
    {/if}
</Layout>
```

the onMount is not triggering at all and it keeps showing the loading div.
My question is how can I import apexcharts using `import ApexCharts from 'apexcharts';` in the svelte file and write all the js scripts in it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use apexcharts in your project you're first going to need to npm I Apexcharts, then you can use this line of code:
import ApexCharts from 'apexcharts'; you can check it out in at the npm docs for apexcharts https://www.npmjs.com/package/apexcharts , I prefer using an npm rather than just using the cdn.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I believe OP isn't asking how to _install_ ApexCharts, but rather how to import it _when using Svelte_.